# How to set the status code of a response?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm using actix for a web application I'm working on, and I'm trying to set the status code 409 to a response, but I don't know how to do that. Something a bit like this:

```
HttpResponse::StatusCode(409).json(Status{
            value: val,
            isOn: true
})
```

Comment: Have you tried [`status`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/dev/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.status)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to explicitly set the status code. The easiest way is to make use of actix-web's [implementation of `Responder` for `(T, StatusCode)` whenever `T: Responder`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/trait.Responder.html#impl-Responder-for-(T%2C%20StatusCode)). Assuming `Status` is some custom struct implementing `Serialize`, you should be able to write something like

```
use actix_web::{HttpRequest, Responder, http, web};

fn foo(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    (
        web::Json(Status {
            value: val,
            isOn: true,
        }),
        http::StatusCode::CONFLICT,
    )
}
```